# "I never get to have any fun" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

Insertion of the word "never" and the verb "get" confuses me a little bit. I'm not sure if he's saying I'm not having fun right now (in the present tense) or I will not have fun anymore (I'll never have fun - future). For me, it sounds like it means I'll no longer have fun but I'd like to confirm that.

Why is the verb "get" used?

Comment: This is a common idiom, though it may take some searching in dictionaries. Try Longman's ['get to do something'](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get-to-do-something).

Comment: @StoneyB Oh I didn't know that it's a common idiom :) Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this context "get" means "to have an opportunity" (see here [english.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/get-to-do-something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/get-to-do-something)). As for the tense, the action refers to something that happens usually, like, "I never get to have any fun whenever I go to birthday parties (it never happens that I enjoy them); I found them so boring."